# ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener не работает

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Здравствуйте. Я написал проект по туториалу андроида http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview_example
И у меня получилось и меню и подменюшки. Далее я попробовал сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на подменюшку открывался html файл, но здесь застрял - ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener не работает.
Поискал в гугле советы - не помогло. Можете пожалуйста посмотреть проект? вот он http://dropmefiles.com/EQdZY

Comment: Что значит не работает?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрел проект.

У вас 2-е ошибки:

Во-первых, в классе адаптера (47 строка) у вас уже описан обработчик клика по элементу списка. Он не даёт "сработать" тому, что описан в активити. Просто удалите его.

Во-вторых, у вас активити 2-ая в манифесте не прописана.

Это исправите и всё заработает.